# R ARIMA model giving odd results

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to use an ARIMA model in R to forecast data. A slice of my time series looks like this:

[image]

This is just a slice of time for you get a sense of it. I have daily data from 2010 to 2015.

I want to forecast this into the future. I'm using the `forecast` library, and my code looks like this:

```
dt = msts(data$val, seasonal.periods=c(7, 30))
fit = auto.arima(dt)
plot(forecast(fit, 300))
```

This results in:

[image]

This model isn't good or interesting. My `seasonal.periods` were defined by me because I expect to see weekly and monthly seasonality, but the result looks the same with no seasonal periods defined.

Am I missing something? Very quickly the forecast predictions change very, very little from point to point.

Edit:

To further show what I'm talking about, here's a concrete example. Let's say I have the following fake dataset:

```
x = 1:500
y = 0.5*c(NA, head(x, -1)) - 0.4*c(NA, NA, head(x, -2)) + rnorm(500, 0, 5)
```

This is an AR(2) model with coefficients `0.5` and `0.4`. Plotting this time series yields:

[image]

So I create an ARIMA model of this and plot the forecast results:

```
plot(forecast(auto.arima(y), 300))
```

And the results are:

[image]

Why can't the ARIMA function learn this obvious model? I don't get any better results if I use the `arima` function and force it to try an AR(2) model.

Comment: That's not an AR(2) model. The lagged terms on the right hand side are for `x`, so the model is a linear trend plus noise. However, `auto.arima` should still be able to do something better than that. It is missing the trend for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

`auto.arima` does not handle multiple seasonal periods. Use `tbats` for that.

```
dt = msts(data$val, seasonal.periods=c(7, 30))
fit = tbats(dt)
plot(forecast(fit, 300))
```

`auto.arima` will just use the largest seasonal period and try to do the best it can with that.

Comment: Hey @Rob Hyndman thanks for this, I didn't realize it. tbats does provide a better result, but I'm still unsure why the arima function can't provide even simple ARIMA models. See my edit.